# Add date and time to a log message in C++

Tags: c++, timestamp

I would like to enquire on how to add timestamp to the log message and save the information to the text file. For instance, if I turn on the equipment, the output will display like this:

[16/03/2021 3:16:00] The equipment is turn on

Thanks!

Comment: It may depend on what compiler/system you have. If `std` is available, check the `chrono` header.

Comment: Hmm I am currently doing on C++

Comment: What OS, what compiler?

Comment: If you have a modern C++ compiler there's a lot of options.

Comment: I am currently doing on Windows, using C++ compiler

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
auto currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); // get the time
auto formattedTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(currentTime); // convert it to time_t type (loses some precision)
std::cout << std::ctime(&formattedTime) << std::endl; // print it formatted
```